# Pandas, build new dataframe with for loop

Tags: python, for-loop, pandas, dataframe

I have a really simple problem that I cant solve in Pandas.
I have a dataframe to start with, with that dataframe I want to apply some function. I want to repeat this many times and build/stack the reults from the operations in a new larger dataframe. I was thinking of doing this with a for loop. Here is a simplified example that I can not get to work:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(3, 4), columns=list('ABCD'))

large_df = df*0

for i in range(1,10):
    df_new = df*i
    large_df= pd.concat(large_df,df_new)

large_df
```

Any ideas??

Comment: `large_df = pd.concat([large_df,df_new])`

Comment: You could just append: `large_df= large_df.append(df_new)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It will be fastest to build all of the results first and concatenate once in the end. If you append one result at a time, the memory for the results has to be re-allocated each time.

So, if you are applying `some_function` with a different parameter `p` through the loop (like `i` in your toy example above) I suggest:

```
pd.concat([df.apply(lambda x: some_function(x, p)) for p in parameters])
```